# Why won't this work? Second function won't register?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
double a;
double b;
a =(3.0);
b =(5.0);
cout << "  " << fixed << setprecision (1) << a << "\n" << endl;
cout << "* " << fixed << setprecision (1) << b << "\n" << endl;
cout << "------" << endl;
cout << fixed << setprecision (2) << a*b << "\n" << endl;

system("PAUSE");

return 0;
}

int calculate ()
{
   double a;
   double b;
   double c;
   a = (7.1);
   b = (8.3);
   c = (2.2);
   cout << fixed << setprecision(1) << endl;
   cout << "  " << fixed << setprecision (1) << a << "\n" << endl;
   cout << "* " << fixed << setprecision (1) << b << "\n" << endl;
   cout << "- " << fixed << setprecision (1) << c << "\n" << endl;
   cout << "------" << endl;
   cout << std::setprecision(2) << (a * b) - c << "\n" << std::endl;

system("PAUSE");

return 0;
}
```

PLEASE don't just tell me to read an intro c++ book or tell me my problem in a vague way, I have 1, it leaves out really tiny details like this. Sadly I've been working on getting this to work for an hour now lol.

Output:

1>------ Build started: Project: 1.2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup
1>c:\users\justin\desktop\1.2\Debug\1.2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: I dont see where you calculate function is invoked.

Comment: You've got a `;` after `calculate()` that shouldn't be there. Once I removed that it compiled in VStudio fine.

Comment: I tried what you said and it does not seem to run....any other ideas?

Comment: how do I "invoke" a function?

Comment: Another word for "invoke" is "call", put a line `calculate();` in `main` for the function to be called in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the source file to the Visual Studio project.

Right click on the "1.2" project in Solution Explorer, select "Add/Existing item..." then navigate to the source file.

Then try building again.

Once you have the build working, you can worry about integrating the call to the `calculate()` function into the program (it'll probably be much easier at that point).

Comment: where is the solution explorer?

Comment: @Justin: Solution Explorer is window that shows the solution, projects and all the files in each project.  If it's not showing, you can activate it from the `View` menu.  You can also add the file to the project using the `Project` menu.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the semicolon after "int calculate()" by mistake? ;)

Comment: ha thank you I have since removed it and it still does not work....any ideas?